# How often do Stack Exchange sites "build"?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

I keep seeing "It will be fixed in the next build" on responses to [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)s and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s.

How often do these "builds" happen? Every day? Every week?

Comment: Every 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: Keep an eye on it yourself. The number is at the bottom of the page. ;)

Comment: It oscillates...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every day, usually multiple times. Looking at the logs, we're averaging between 3 and 4 production builds per day (usually fewer on the weekend and more during the week). In the lower right of every page you can see the build identifier. Currently it says

> rev 2013.2.8.1401

where 2013.2.8 is obviously the date (meaning that the last build was today), and 1401 is the TeamCity-assigned build number. That number by itself doesn't have a direct meaning, but when it changes, you know that a build has happened.