# Can't navigate to other "tabs" with keyboard shortcuts from tag info tab

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, keyboard-shortcuts

After seeing the annoucement, [Announcement: Keyboard shortcuts are now integrated into the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237166/225437), I just had to enable keyboard shortcuts.  I ran into the following problem, which is not one of those mentioned in [New keyboard shortcut integration problems?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237250/225437)

On pages displaying lists of questions, the O shortcut is described as "order questions by", but it actually appears to be a way to switch between the different tabs on that page. Usually those are synonymous, but not so when browsing questions by tag. E.g., when [browsing questions tagged with Jena](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7V0f.png), the leftmost tab is "info", which is not a question ordering:

[image: we can select the tag info tag from the list of tagged questions]

That said, pressing O, then I, *does* bring us to the info tab, but once we're there, we can't be *back* to the other tabs.  O isn't enabled on the tag info page (there's nothing to order, I suppose), but there aren't any shortcuts to get to the other tabs, either:

[image: but we can't get to the question tabs from a tag info tab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that it's a bit weird to have "info" appear as a "sort order", but I don't have a good idea to change this at the moment. I have however fixed the main bug in your report; the <kbd>O</kbd> shortcut will work on the tag info page from the next build on.

Comment: Yes, "info" as a sort order didn't make a lot of sense, but the real problem was not being able to get back *from* it.  If the UI is actually about those tabs rather than sort order, an easy fix would be to change the text for O to something like "Open tab".

Comment: Will this fix require some time to propagate? I don't see it on Stack Overflow yet...

Comment: My answer says "from the next build on"; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166787/how-often-do-stack-exchange-sites-build for some details.

Comment: D'oh! Sorry, I read much too quickly.  Thanks for the quick fix!